# unrecognized selector sent to instance when getting parameter value in cellForRowAt SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

[image]I am populating a `Tableview` with items fetched by `itemsFetchResultController` but when getting the fetched parameters as in

`let item = itemFetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath).itemName!`

I get

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSKnownKeysDictionary1
>   itemName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60000078a2e0

I looked in many posts but nothing seem to work. In one post it's suggested that the returned object is type of `NSManagedObject` hence has not selector for properties.

If I instead try to get the properties as in

`let item = itemFetchedResultController!.fetchedObjects![indexPath.row]`

I get

> Thread 1: Fatal error: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array
>   Element type

I tried casting the object as `NSArray` but didn't solve the problem. How do I get access to fetched objects parameters values?

Here is the code for both fetching an populating:

```
func configureItemFetchedResultsController() {
        print("configureItemFetchedResultsController(): started")
        let itemFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Item")
        itemFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "category", ascending: true),NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemId", ascending: true)]
        let user = NSPredicate(format: "order.user.name == %@", UserDetails.fullName ?? "")
        let dateFrom = Conversions.dateConvert(dateString: dateToFetchMin)!
        let dateTo = Conversions.dateConvert(dateString: dateToFetchMax)!
        print(dateFrom)
        let from = NSPredicate(format: "date >= %@", dateFrom as CVarArg)
        let to = NSPredicate(format: "date <= %@", dateTo as CVarArg)
        itemFetchRequest.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [user,from,to])
        itemFetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = ["category","itemId","itemName"]]
        itemFetchRequest.returnsDistinctResults = true
        itemFetchRequest.propertiesToGroupBy = ["category","itemId","itemName"]
        itemFetchRequest.resultType = NSFetchRequestResultType.dictionaryResultType 

        itemFetchedResultController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: itemFetchRequest, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: "category", cacheName: nil) as? NSFetchedResultsController<Item>
        do {
            try itemFetchedResultController?.performFetch()
            let resultsDict = itemFetchedResultController!.fetchedObjects!
            print(resultsDict as NSArray)
            print("configureItemFetchedResultsController(): sold items fetched")
        } catch  {
            //            fatalError("failed to fetch entities: \(error)")
            print("configureItemFetchedResultsController(): failed to fetch Item entities: \(error)")
        }
        self.statisticsTableView.reloadData()
    }


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "statisticsCell", for: indexPath) as! StatisticsTableViewCell
        let item = itemFetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath).itemName!
        //        let item = itemResultsArray[indexPath.row]
        let productRequest: NSFetchRequest<Product> = Product.fetchRequest()
        productRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]
        productRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", item!)
        productRequest.fetchLimit = 1
        do {
            let fetch = try context.fetch(productRequest)
            cell.idInfoLabel.text = fetch[0].productId
            cell.nameInfoLabel.text = fetch[0].name
            cell.productImageView.image = UIImage(data: (fetch[0].productImage! as Data))
            cell.minimumStockInfoLabel.text = fetch[0].minimumStock
            let productPrice = fetch[0].price
            //fetch item for amount of single object
            let itemId = itemFetchedResultController?.object(at: indexPath).itemId!
            let itemRequest = NSFetchRequest<Item>(entityName: "Item")
            itemRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "itemName", ascending: true)]
            itemRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date BEGINSWITH %@", dateToFetchMin)
            itemRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "itemId == %@", itemId!)
            do {
                let itemFetch = try context.fetch(itemRequest)
                print(productPrice!)
                print(itemFetch, itemFetch.count)
                cell.soldQuantityInfoLabel.text = String(describing: itemFetch.count)
                let amount = Double(productPrice!)! * Double(itemFetch.count)
                cell.salesAmountInfoLabel.text = String(describing: amount)
            } catch  {
                print("Error in fetching sold items for cell: \(error)")
            }
        } catch  {
            print("Error in fetching product for cell: \(error)")
        }
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Why do you perform two(!) fetches in `cellForRow`? That's unnecessary expensive. Use relationships. The error occurs because you specified a dictionary as result type in the fetched results controller. Don't do that. Use always the `NSManagedObject` subclass as result type. And create the result controller as non-optional lazy instantiated property as suggested in the Core Data template.

Comment: @vadian I am forced to use dictionary as I want distinct results for fetched result controller. as for the two fetches in `cellForRowAt` I use the first to get all detail for the `Product` entity which `Item` entity reflect partially. `Product` is the product in the catalog, `Item` is child of `Order` entity.
`Tableview`is displaying all items in orders between two dates divided by  product category, so if I don't use `.propertiesToFetch` , `.propertiesToGroupBy` and  `.dictionaryResultType `, `.returnsDistinctResults = true`won't work and I'll have one cell per sold `Item` in `Tableview`.

Comment: If `Dictionary` is mandatory you have to declare the results controller as `NSFetchedResultsController<NSDictionary>` and then you have to get all values by key subscription.

Comment: I know it's a bit of an expensive code, but it's the best solution I could came up with. I'd love to code it in a more elegant

Comment: @vadian oh sure!  that's why I got the `has not subscripts`error when I tried it. Thank you very much. You solved many of errors since I started

Comment: @vadian I'd love a hint on a better approach to achieve what I'm messily trying to accomplish with this code, so to get better at logic here in swift. Thanks again

Comment: Without knowing the Core Data model it's very hard to suggest something.

Comment: @vadian I just tested it and it works as I wanted. Many thanks I have to admit that I wasted almost two days on this. A screenshot for the Core Data model would be enough to show?

Comment: Yes, but this is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Sure, is not my intention to take advantage of you, you're always so available. Should I ask another question instead?

Comment: You should ask questions regarding code improvement in Code Review Stack Exchange

Comment: Great! I'll do that than. Thanks again maestro.